# Spring framework 1.1.2 - Challenging...using the command line javac compiler with no Build Tools (Maven or Gradle..etc)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, command-line, javac

Purpose :

I am trying to build a simple Spring Application using spring framework 1.1.2. This dates back to 2004. The idea was to understand how the framework progressed from being a bunch of classes to introducing Annotations and a plethora of ways reducing what the developer had to do. I am using the example 
(Spring-MVC-step-by-step) distributed with the spring framework 1.1.2 dist, which provides the jars that spring was based on at that time.

Problem :

The problem is when you do not use a build tool and create all the directory structure yourself (src, war, WEB-INF) and place your .java , .jsp in the appropriate folders.. the javac compiler struggles to find the spring associated jars using the classpath env variable. I have all the associated spring jars placed into a folder and the CLASSPATH set accordingly..however the javac compiler throws the following errors

SpringAppController.java:1: error: package org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc does not exist

SpringAppController.java:2: error: package org.springframework.web.servlet does not exist

SpringAppController.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
import java.io.Exception;

No matter where you place the jars the compiler is unable to locate and use them.

Does anyone have an idea on how a simple Spring application can be built using the javac and a notepad editor without any support of any build tool ?

Even a ton of search on stackoverflow does not show any results on such an attempt. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry folks.. This was stupid.. I just had to add each spring framework .jar file separately on the CLASSPATH and that was enough for the javac compiler to find the appropriate packages.

Comment: Could you add a cmd example?